# Number Product Triangle in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python at the moment via an online course but I have been stuck on the following assignment of generating the following Triangle.

```
1
2  4
3  6  9
4  8 12 16
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

I was giving the following code

```py
rows = [
    n   # TODO: fix this
    for n in range(1,8)
]

print '\n' +'\n'.join(rows)
```

but I cannot for the life of me figure out how its done and it doesn't help that I haven't looked at it in over a month as when I last looked at it I was able to print out the first row but now I am unable to do that.

I know if I use the following code

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    print repr(x).rjust(1),
    print repr(x*x).rjust(2),
    print repr(x*x*x).rjust(3)
```

it will give me

```
1  1   1
2  4   8
3  9  27
```

but I dont know where to go from there.

Comment: I'd try thinking of it the other way - as a list of rows, each containing multiples of a number up to the number's square.

Comment: You may need two `for` loops, one for the rows and another one for the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reasonably close to what you want:

```
>>> rows = [
    ' '.join(map(str, range(n, n * n + 1, n)))
    for n in range(1, 8)
]
>>> print('\n' + '\n'.join(rows))

1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
>>>
```

A demonstration of the code can be found on [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/lA5XKy).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[str(t * i) for t in range(1, i + 1)] for i in range(1, 8)]

for l in a:
    print(" ".join(l))
```

1. Generating required list of lists
2. Printing each inner list in a separate line